# lxml adds urlencoding in xml?

Tags: python, lxml

I'll preface this by indicating I'm using Python 2.7.3 (x64) on Windows 7, with lxml 2.3.6.

I have a little, odd, problem I'm hoping somebody can help with.  I haven't find a solution online, perhaps I'm not searching for the right thing.

Anyway, I have a problem where I'm programmatically building some XML with lxml, then outputting this to a text file, the problem is lxml is converting carriage returns to the text `&#13;`, almost like urlencoding - but I'm not using HTML I'm using XML.

For example, I have a simple text file created in Notepad, like this:

```
This
is
my
text
```

I then build some xml and add this text into the xml:

```
from lxml import etree

textstr = ""
fh = open("mytext.txt", "rb")
for line in fh:
    textstr += line

root = etree.Element("root")
a = etree.SubElement(root, "some_element")
a.text = textstr

print etree.tostring(root)
```

The problem here is the output of the print looks like this:

```
<root><some_element>This&#13;
is&#13;
my&#13;
text</some_element></root>
```

For my purposes the line breaks are fine, but the `&#13;` elements are not.

What I have been able to figure out is that this is happening because I'm opening the text file in binary mode `"rb"` (which I actually need to do as my app is indexing a large text file).  If I don't open the file in binary mode `"r"`, then the output does not contain `&#13;` (but of course, then my indexing doesn't work).

I've also tried changing the `etree.tostring` to:

```
print etree.tostring(root, method="xml")
```

However there is no difference in the output.

Now, I CAN dump the xml text to a string then do a replace of the `$#13;` artifacts, however, I was hoping for a more elegant solution - because the text files I parse are not under my control and I'm worried that other elements of the text file might be converted to url style encoding without my knowledge.

Does anyone know a way of preventing this encoding from happening?

Comment: What you mean by "my indexing doesn't work". There is no evidence of it in your post. Perhaps the solution is to fix the indexing and open the file in text mode... hard to tell without more information.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends

Comment: @isdev The indexer I'm using happens to open the file in "rb" mode, so I was looking for a solution that didn't require a change there.  I'm sure indexing is possible in non-binary mode, but I was hoping to not go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses `\r\n` to represent a line ending, Unix uses `\n`.
This will remove the `\r` at the end of the line, if there is one there (so the code will work with unix text files too.) It will remove at most one `\r`, so if there is an `\r` somewhere else in the line it will be preserved.

```
import re
textstr = ""
with open("mytext.txt", "rb") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        textstr += re.sub(r'\r$', '', line)
print(repr(textstr))
```

Comment: I'm never going to be using unix style files, but this works for me!  Thanks!